# Log4j2: XML Log file changes in pattern layout to capture milli seconds- sss

Tags: java, xml, logfile

I need to capture the time in milli seconds in the log4j2.xml file. I have changed the  file pattern

```
filePattern="./logs/application/ceba.${sys:weblogic.Name:-}.log%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}">
```

how do I change my pattern layout to reflect the time in milli second?

Currently this is my pattern layout:

```
   <PatternLayout>
 <Pattern>%d %t %-5p %c - %m%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by using %d{UNIX_MILLIS} as in [Manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html)

> %d{UNIX} outputs the UNIX time in seconds. %d{UNIX_MILLIS} outputs the UNIX time in milliseconds. The UNIX time is the difference, in seconds for UNIX and in milliseconds for UNIX_MILLIS, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. While the time unit is milliseconds, the granularity depends on the operating system (Windows). This is an efficient way to output the event time because only a conversion from long to String takes place, there is no Date formatting involved.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %t %-5p %c - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
```